# change image with Jquery - images over each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Jquery

```
switch (catSelected) {
    case (""):
        if (city == 1) {
            cityName = "ROME";
            $("#banner_img").css("background-image", "url(/images/HomePageBanner/rome_home1.jpg)");
            $("#homePageGallery1 img").attr("src", "/images/TourListBanner/VatBannernew.png");
            $("#homePageGallery1").find("a").attr("href", "/official-vatican-museum-partnership");
            $("#homePageGallery1 img").show();
            break;
        }
        else if(city == 0) {
            cityName = "VATICAN";
            $("#banner_img").css("background-image", "url(/images/TourListBanner/vatican1.jpg)");
            $("#homePageGallery1 img").attr("src", "/images/TourListBanner/VatBannernew.png");
            $("#homePageGallery1").find("a").attr("href", "/official-vatican-museum-partnership");
            break;
        }
```

It changes the top banner picture when you change a category.  The problem is that there is already a picture and i don't know how to get rid of it or display the new picture on top of it.

top banner after I change the category :

```
<img id="banner_img" class="resrc" style="height: auto; max-width: 1600px; width: 100%; background-image: url(http://localhost:45000/images/TourListBanner/colosseum-ancient-rome1.jpg);" data-src="http://app.resrc.it/o=85/http://www.x.com/images/listings/rome.jpg" alt="" data-resrc-width="1600" src="http://app.resrc.it/s=w1600,pd1/o=85/http://www.x.com/images/listings/rome.jpg">
```

I think I need to use the google jquery change image attributes

Comment: Can you expand a little, your question is not really clear, maybe add a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, $(this).attr("src", src); and delete whats there at the moment, it was putting image over image